# Can I see the video version of the double-slit experiment that include detectors at the slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

> Furthermore, versions of the experiment that include detectors at the slits find that each detected photon passes through one slit (as would a classical particle), and not through both slits (as would a wave). Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment

Comment: Are you looking for an animation that visualizes the results described, or do you want a physical setup that produces those results?

Comment: @JohnDvorak I want to see a real experiment video.

Comment: Of course, a video cannot show photons.  It can only show detection events, like clicks or meter deflections, counters, photographic plates, etc.

Comment: Such a video is impossible: even if we were able technically to follow the propagation of electrons, we would be able to tell via which slit the electron passes - this would trigger the collapse of the quantum superposition and disappearance of the interference picture. This collapse of the superposition has been extensively studied in so-called *which path? detectors.* I will be happy to repost this as an answer, if the question is reopened.

Comment: @Vadim I am sorry, but I don't know why my question is closed.